# MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007

Tags: java, android, camera, video-recording

I'm trying to implement video recording with "old" camera api (not camera2), and recently I've faced with an error I can't fix(
The problem is when I call stop() method to stop recording the app is crashing. Start() works fine and I can't figure it out what is the problem. The app has all permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>
```

The CameraPreview class looks like following:

```
public class CameraHelperOld extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


private final String mVideoPath;
Camera mCamera;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

public CameraHelperOld(Context context, String videoPath) {
    super(context);
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mVideoPath = videoPath;

    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoPath);

        mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d("Error","error");
            }
        });
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder().getSurface());

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
    mMediaRecorder.release();

    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

}

I'm calling the Stop() method in surfaceDestroyed() - and it is definitely not a problem, coz I was calling it from different places.

Now, I've tried all solution suggestions I've found but none of them worked. Could anyone explain me what is the reason of such behaviour?

BTW, I'm using Nexus 5 LG.

I implemented video recording with Camera2 API successfully, but I need the app to work with old Camera API, since I need a support for KitKat and older android devices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The deprecated camera API works on modern devices through tricky compatibility shims; you cannot derive from this how your code will work on KitKat devices, or on API 21+ phones with old camera HAL. Vice versa, if your code works well with native camera2 API, it may still fail miserably on devices with LEGACY camera. I find it much more reliable to use the old camera API on such devices, even though lint warns about deprecation.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, @AlexCohn, that's why I'm using old camera API. But with the problem of stopping the recording process(

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough: You cannot use Nexus 5 as a test device for old Camera API. Even emulator will give you a better test case.

Comment: @AlexCohn, Would it be a solution to use both camera API (camera and camera2) at the same time - first for support of old devices with KitKat and older versions of android, and another for newest one?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I recommend to do: have two classes that wrap camera operations for you, one for pre-21 devices *and* newer devices with LEGACY camera, second – for devices that have true camera2 support.

Comment: Many thanks, @AlexCohn!! Will try it!

Comment: It has nothing to do with Camera API, `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);` - works buggy on some devices, for my Xiaomi rebooting temporary helps to avoid 1007 error

Comment: @user25 you are right, `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)` is the couse of problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user25, @francis, so, guys, what to do with `MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE`? I can't use anything else because I have openGl surface for preview.